# Copying files in Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-system

I recently watched a video in which the speaker said that Haskell is not suited for real-world tasks, such as copying files from one folder to another.
So I tried to write a program that copies a given file system tree to a new location. The usage of the program is

```
copy_tree <source path> <target path>
```

If the target path does not exists, it is created. Then all folders and files under `<source path>` are copied to `<target path>`. Here is my `copy_tree.hs` source. I would like to have feedback and suggestions on how to improve it. Especially, I would like to make it as succinct and as idiomatic as possible.

One thing that I do not like very much is that the code calls `doesDirectoryExist` twice.

```
import System.Directory
import System.Environment
import System.FilePath


getSubitems path = getSubitemsRec ""
  where
    getChildren path = do
        isDir <- doesDirectoryExist path
        if isDir
          then fmap (filter (`notElem` [".", ".."])) (getDirectoryContents path)
          else return []

    getSubitemsRec relPath = do
        children <- getChildren (path </> relPath)
        let relChildren = [relPath </> p | p <- children]
        nephewItems <- mapM getSubitemsRec relChildren
        return (relChildren ++ (concat nephewItems))


copyItem baseSourcePath baseTargetPath relativePath = do
    let sourcePath = baseSourcePath </> relativePath
    let targetPath = baseTargetPath </> relativePath

    putStrLn $ "Copying " ++ sourcePath ++ " to " ++ targetPath
    isDir <- doesDirectoryExist sourcePath
    if isDir
      then createDirectoryIfMissing False targetPath
      else copyFile sourcePath targetPath


copyTree s t = do
    subItems <- getSubitems s
    createDirectoryIfMissing True t
    mapM_ (copyItem s t) subItems


main = do
    args <- getArgs
    if (length args) == 2
      then copyTree (args !! 0) (args !! 1)
      else putStrLn "Usage: copy_tree <source> <target>"
```

Answer (score 1):

> One thing that I do not like very much is that the code calls
>   `doesDirectoryExist` twice.

You can return the result of the `doesDirectoryExist` from `getSubitems` and pass it to `copyItem`, obviating the duplicate call.

> Especially, I would like to make it as succinct and as idiomatic as
>   possible.

You can use low precedence `<$>` instead of `fmap` to remove some parentheses.

Also `"."` and `".."` should be returned once from `getDirectoryContents`, so you can replace the

```
(filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]))
```

with `(\\ [".", ".."])`.

### Slight Behavior Difference between `copyTree` and `copyTree'`

Behavior of `copyTree'` is slightly different from `copyTree`, in that it will accept files as well as directories as parameter `s`. This is due to the fact that `getSubitems'` includes the input parameter (`path`, root of the subtree) in the descendants list it returns. You can get back the previous behavior by ignoring the first value returning from the `getSubitems'` in `copyTree'`. But I left the change in `copyTree'` as is for a behavior more consistent with `cp -R` of POSIX.

### Modified Code

```
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Data.List ((\\))

getSubitems' :: FilePath -> IO [(Bool, FilePath)]
getSubitems' path = getSubitemsRec ""
  where
    getChildren path =  (\\ [".", ".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents path

    getSubitemsRec relPath = do
        let absPath = path </> relPath
        isDir <- doesDirectoryExist absPath
        children <- if isDir then getChildren absPath else return []
        let relChildren = [relPath </> p | p <- children]
        ((isDir, relPath) :) . concat <$> mapM getSubitemsRec relChildren

copyItem' baseSourcePath baseTargetPath (isDir, relativePath) = do
    let sourcePath = baseSourcePath </> relativePath
    let targetPath = baseTargetPath </> relativePath

    putStrLn $ "Copying " ++ sourcePath ++ " to " ++ targetPath
    if isDir
      then createDirectoryIfMissing False targetPath
      else copyFile sourcePath targetPath

copyTree' s t = do
    createDirectoryIfMissing True t
    subItems <- getSubitems' s
    mapM_ (copyItem' s t) subItems
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). What do you mean that the behavior is (of (\\ [".", ".."])) is slightly different? Since `getDirectoryContents` returns these two strings at the front of the list, in this case the behaviour should be the same.

Comment: I'll clarify it with an edit. You're right: expected behavior is the same for `\\`. I meant that the behavior of `getSubitems'` is slightly different from `getSubitems` in that in returns the root item (parameter `path`) also.